# iOS SDK: ARC removeFromSuperview

Tags: ios, view, uiview, automatic-ref-counting

I have a simple question regarding ARC. I show a UIView if a user taps a button using addSuperView within a UIViewController. The UIView contains a close button, if tapped I want to remove the view.

I used to call a method within the UIViewController after animating the view offscreen:

```
- (void)viewDidClose:(UIView *)view
{
     [view removeFromSuperview];
     [view release], view = nil;
}
```

Now using ARC I changed it to:

```
- (void)viewDidClose:(UIView *)view
{
     [view removeFromSuperview];
     view = nil;
}
```

The question now is: I want to remove the protocol and the delegation to the view controller and do this within the UIView itself.

Pre-ARC (within view):

```
- (void)didStop
{
     [self removeFromSuperview];
     [self autorelease];
}
```

I can't use 'autorelease' in ARC nor set 'self = nil', as far as I know ARC comes in place as soon as I set the view to nil or replace it, but what if I don't replace it? Is [view removeFromSuperview] enough to take care of everything or does this leak?

Thanks a lot! I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

(Note that in your non-ARC version, you'd want the `autorelease` before the `removeFromSuperview`).

I've wondered about similar things. The 'danger' is that when you do the `removeFromSuperview` without first doing an `autorelease`, the object is immediately deallocated, even before the end of the method. That's skeezy.

My idea was that you'd make the method return `self`. In the non-ARC case, you'd create this pointer with `autorelease` but ARC should do that for you. You may not need the pointer in the caller, but I believe this will force ARC to do what you want.